# Is it possible to parcel/deparcel a list of different objects that extend same base class?

Tags: java, android, parcelable, parcel

Say I have a base abstract class(or an interface), called "Base" and several concrete classes that extend it, like Concrete1, Concrete2, Concrete3. Now, I have another Container class that contains a list of "Base" objects:

```
public class Container implements Parcelable {
  ...
  private List<Base> baseList;

}
```

Let's say I want to put several concrete objects into baseList:

```
baseList.add(new Concrete1());
baseList.add(new Concrete2());
baseList.add(new Concrete3());
baseList.add(new Concrete2());
```

Is it possible to implement parceling for baseList field and have a list of objects of the same types Concrete1, Concrete2, etc. after deparceling? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following approach.

1. Make sure that `Base` implements `Parcelable`.
2. Put a `describeContents` method in `Base`.
3. Put a method `abstract void write2(Parcel p);` method in `Base` and override it in each concrete class.
4. Put a method `static Base create2(Parcel p)` in each concrete class. This should be the reverse of `write2`.
5. Write an abstract method `abstract int typeNumber()` in `Base` and override it in each concrete subclass (each subclass should return a different value. I use static final fields `CONCRETE1`, `CONCRETE2`, ... that I keep in `Base`).

Then you can add the following to `Base`:

```
@Override
public final void writeToParcel(Parcel p, int flags) {
    p.writeInt(typeNumber());
    write2(p);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {

    @Override
    public Base createFromParcel(Parcel p) {
        switch (p.readInt()) {
            case CONCRETE1: return Concrete1.create2(p);
            case CONCRETE2: return Concrete2.create2(p);
            // etc
            default: throw new AssertionError();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Base[] newArray(int size) {
         return new Base[size];
    }
}
```

Then you can write a `List` using

```
parcel.writeTypedList(baseList);
```

and read it back using

```
List<Base> list = new ArrayList<Base>();
parcel.readTypedList(list, Base.CREATOR);
```

This approach does not require the names of any classes to be written to the `Parcel` (it writes `int` values instead), does not require the `CREATOR` fields to be found using reflection, and does not require a `ClassLoader`.

Comment: Tried that just now, I get an exception: "Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: <class name>" I suspect it's because passing null in parcel.readList(list, null); prevents it from finding the correct classloader to instantiate a class.

Comment: Really. Oh ok. I'm in the middle of editing my answer anyway.

Comment: @AntonCherkashyn Try this. There may be some typos in that, but the approach definitely works as it's how I do it. I wrote the other answer using something I'd never tried, which was a daft thing to do.

Comment: This is very interesting, I got your previous code to work by passing base class classloader to readList: "parcel.readList(list, Base.class.getClassLoader());" and it instantiated a concrete object Concrete1 just fine. I'm not sure if this is always going to work though, in my case Base and Concrete1 happen to be in the same package, perhaps this matters. I'll try your new code too.

Comment: @AntonCherkashyn That's interesting, but I don't really know why passing `null` didn't work. TBH I don't really understand the classloader approach anyway.

Comment: @AntonCherkashyn I slightly changed the above just now. I replaced a `CREATOR` field in each subclass with a static method `create2`. You shouldn't put a `CREATOR` in every subclass because if you do it that way the write/create methods are not the reverse of one another.

Comment: But this would mean that the `Base` class has to know about it's children. Each time a new child is created, `Base` class has to be modified. That's bad.